# because button is white by default in python, png image background becomes white when I add png image

Tags: python, button, png, transparency, opacity

[I added this button with "add command-response" in png format, but because the default color of the button is white, when I add a png image, its background becomes white.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZxQc.png)

[I made the background of the button purple so you can fully understand the problem. note: there is no color in the code of the button, normally I made the color purple so you can understand it.

no background= or bg= used in button code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KhUv.png)

I added a blue button and tried to remove the background of this button but it didn't work. Wherever I looked I couldn't find any code to fix it. alpha vs... i tried all the codes and it didn't work